# Bootstrap Accordion rotate icon when open

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap 4 accordion, What I need is the icon to rotate and point up conditionally when the accordion is "open" and back down when it is closed. I was able to do this with css but I need it to happen conditionally as there are "active" states and not events that should trigger the accordions open if that makes sense.

HTML:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion-nav">

    <div class="accordion-item">
        <div class="item-header" id="heading">
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-nav-accordion" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#collapseDosing" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseDosing">
                <span>panel</span>
                <i class="fas fa-chevron-down "></i>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseDosing" class="collapse collapse-nav-accordion"
            aria-labelledby="heading-dosing" data-parent="#accordion-nav">
            <div class="accordion-body">
                <div class="l-accordion-body">
                   <h1>Body</h1>>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion-item accordion-item--savings">
        <div class="item-header" id="heading-savings">
            <button class="btn btn-link btn-nav-accordion" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#collapseSavings" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseSavings">
                <span>panel</span>
                <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseSavings" class="collapse collapse-nav-accordion"
            aria-labelledby="heading-savings" data-parent="#accordion-nav">
            <div class="accordion-body">
                <div class="l-accordion-body">
                 <h1>Body</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css: (did work on click event) but need another way conditionally (js) I would think

```
.btn-nav-accordion[aria-expanded="true"] {
  .fa-chevron-down {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

js: currently works but does not remove the class when I click the accordion to close now

```
 $(".collapse-nav-accordion").each(function () {
      var currentAccordion = this;
      if ($(currentAccordion).hasClass("show")) {
        $(currentAccordion).parent().find("i").addClass("rotate");
      } else {
        $(currentAccordion).parent().find("i").removeClass("rotate");
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using scss that needs compiling into css. Also your js isn't needed.

```
.btn-nav-accordion[aria-expanded="true"] .fa-chevron-down {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```css
.fa-chevron-up {
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
 }
.btn-nav-accordion.collapsed .fa-chevron-up {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="accordion" id="accordion-nav">

  <div class="accordion-item">
    <div class="item-header" id="heading">
      <button class="btn btn-link btn-nav-accordion collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseDosing" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseDosing">
                <span>panel</span>
                <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
            </button>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseDosing" class="collapse collapse-nav-accordion" aria-labelledby="heading-dosing" data-parent="#accordion-nav">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <div class="l-accordion-body">
          <h1>Body</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-item accordion-item--savings">
    <div class="item-header" id="heading-savings">
      <button class="btn btn-link btn-nav-accordion" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseSavings" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseSavings">
                <span>panel</span>
                <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
            </button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseSavings" class="collapse collapse-nav-accordion show" aria-labelledby="heading-savings" data-parent="#accordion-nav">
      <div class="accordion-body">
        <div class="l-accordion-body">
          <h1>Body</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not correct, yes it does work but how I have it nested (scss) also works as well. My problem is want the icon to rotate based on the .collapse show. I am adding "show" to the collapse dynamically on some pages so when the user sees the accordion the icon is pointing up and accordion is open, now if they close the accordion at that point I need to return to original state of down. What is happening now is the icon just stays pointing up. Thanks for the input :)

Comment: Hey, If I've understood correctly your issue is that you want some accordions to be open on page load? If so, I've updated my comment showing one of the panels open on load.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
if ($(currentAccordion).hasClass("show")) {
    $(currentAccordion).parent().find("i").addClass("rotate");
  } else {
    $(currentAccordion).parent().find("i").removeClass("rotate");
  }
```

you're using class "rotate", but you haven't specified what "rotate" does - is it another css definition (like `.rotate {transform: rotate(180deg);})` or is it a js behavior, (like `if (el.hasClass('rotate')) { el.style.transform = rotate(180deg); }`?

Alternatively, I like to just toggle classes, switching between fa-chevron-down and fa-chevron-up:

```
if (el.hasClass('rotate') { 
    el.classList.replace('fa-chevron-down', 'fa-chevron-up');
} else {
    el.classList.replace('fa-chevron-up', 'fa-chevron-down');
}
```